# How to manage pages in liferay?

Tags: liferay, html

I am new to Liferay I have created two `UserGroups` - Grp1 (with users a1, b1, c1) and Grp2 (with users a2, b2, c2).

Groupwise some public and private pages are created which differentiates Grp1 task from Grp2.

1. I want user a2, b2, c2 to have there own private pages which only they can view.
2. And when I login through user say a2, by default liferay's public page is viewed and, in **GO TO** user's (a2) public and private page is available.

   Can't on login itself users public and private page be viewed and not liferay's default page?
3. And how does `GROUP LEVEL` and `USER LEVEL` public & private pages differ?

I created pages at group level (Grp2) both public and private, all the pages are visible to a2, b2, c2. On adding a page (a2) it behaves as private page only a2 can view it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want user a2, b2, c2 to have there own private pages which only they can view.

- Then use User level private pages. Which you can see in `GO TO` menu with url `http://localhost/user/a2/home`
- These pages will be automatically created when a user is added to liferay. You can control the creation of these pages by modifying the following properties in [`portal.properties`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L4322):

  ```
  layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=true
  layout.user.private.layouts.auto.create=true
  ```

  You can also check out the section [Default User Private Layouts](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L4120) in `portal.properties` to get some more idea.
- These pages are visible only to the users and only the users have full control over it.
- More about this in Liferay User Guide's section on [User personal site](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen06-user-personal-sites-0).
  -

> Can't on login itself users public and private page be viewed and not liferay's default page?

- For this you can will have to create a login-post-action-hook.
- You will need to modify the property: `login.events.post` in your hook and include a `CustomLandingPageAction` class on the lines of [`DefaultLandingPageAction`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/DefaultLandingPageAction.java#L36).
- This is good resource to create [Custom Landing Page](http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/07/custom-landing-page-using-hook-liferay.html).

> And how does GROUP LEVEL and USER LEVEL public & private pages differ?

- I think you are asking about difference between UserGroup Level (instead of just Group) and User Level.
- Please see section [User Group Sites](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-user-groups-0) in Liferay User-guide, some relevant excerpt from the section:

  ```
  Liferay allows users to each have a personal site consisting of public and
  private pages. Permissions can be granted to allow users to customize their
  personal sites at will. Originally, the default configuration of those pages
  could only be determined by the portal administrator through the
  portal-ext.properties file and, optionally, by providing the configuration in
  a LAR file. You can still configure it like this but it isn’t very flexible or
  easy to use.

  By using User Group Sites, portal administrators can add pages to the personal
  sites of all the users who belong to the site in an easy and centralized way.
  All the user group site’s public pages are shown as part of the user’s public
  personal site. All the user group site’s private pages are shown as part of the
  user’s private site. If a user belongs to several user groups, all of its pages
  are made part of his public and private site. In an educational institution’s
  portal, for example, teachers, staff and students could get different default
  pages and applications on their personal sites.
  ```

Hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Hey prakash thanks for your reply.<br>Go To got removed when i add 'layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false <br>layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false'